# Countdown timer in flash frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a countdown timer in flash. This timer shows time in a dynamic text field with myTimer instance name. My app in flash have some frames with next and back button that user can go next or back frame. The timer code inserted in action panel directly in the first frame. My issue is this: When I click on next or back button to go other frames,the timer disappear for a moment in new frame (about 1 second last to show timer)? How I can fix this?

```
  start_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, starter);

  function starter(event:MouseEvent):void
  {

var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,120);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
timer.start();
function countdown(event:TimerEvent)
{
    var totalSecondsLeft:Number = 120 - timer.currentCount;
    if (totalSecondsLeft==0)
    {
        gotoAndStop(18);
    }
    myTimer.text = timeFormat(totalSecondsLeft);
}
function timeFormat(seconds:int):String
{
    var minutes:int;
    var sMinutes:String;
    var sSeconds:String;
    if (seconds > 59)
    {
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        sMinutes = String(minutes);
        sSeconds = String(seconds % 60);
    }
    else
    {
        sMinutes = "";
        sSeconds = String(seconds);
    }
    if (sSeconds.length == 1)
    {
        sSeconds = "0" + sSeconds;
    }
    return sMinutes + ":" + sSeconds;
}
nextFrame();
    }
```

Comment: I say put the items you want to remain on all frames (next/prev buttons, timer, maybe other butons) outside of the MC you shift frames, this will eliminate your problem outright, as the timer's parent MC won't change frames.

Comment: I created a new object  (_timerContainer_) and moved the _myTimer_ into it and it solved. Thank you.